# How to use random number in shell script?

Tags: shell, random

With the shell script, I wish to generate five files, and I wish to put different random number range from 50000~150000 in each file. I tried something like following,

```
for i in 01 02 03 04 05; do
A=$((50000+100000))
B=$(($B%$A))
cat > ${i}.dat << EOF
AArandom=$A
EOF
done
```

But this does not work.... How can I make random numbers and print out for each file?

Comment: @Steve not a duplicate, because of the range requirement: `$RANDOM` produces numbers in the range `0 - 32767`, but here a bigger range is required.

Comment: If you want to do something in bash, `man bash` is often a good way to start. The man page is long; search for keywords, like `random`...

Comment: I think the question should be reworded to explicitly note the range >32767 requirement.

Comment: In the above loop `$B` wasn't used to output anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you read the value of the variable `$RANDOM`,
it gives you a random number between 0 and `2^15 - 1`,
that is 0 and 32767. So that doesn't give you enough range.
You could use two `$RANDOM` as two digits of base-15,
and then take appropriate modulo and apply appropriate range normalization.

Here's the logic wrapped in a function:

```
randrange() {
    min=$1
    max=$2

    ((range = max - min))

    ((maxrand = 2**30))
    ((limit = maxrand - maxrand % range))

    while true; do
        ((r = RANDOM * 2**15 + RANDOM))
        ((r < limit)) && break
    done

    ((num = min + r % range))
    echo $num
}
```

And then you can generate the files in a loop like this:

```
for i in 01 02 03 04 05; do
  echo "AArandom=$(randrange 50000 150000)" > $i.dat
done
```

Note that there is a caveat in the implementation of `randrange`:
there is a loop to re-roll in case the value would be biased,
but theoretically this may prevent the function from terminating.
In practice, that's extremely unlikely, but deserves a mention.

Comment: Nice solution to extend the range. The result is biased though, so you'll want to use a different construct if you want a completely uniform distribution. To see why, consider a range of 1 less than the highest number which can be handled by randrange, (2^15-1) * 2^15 + (2^15-1). Using that range there are exactly one combination of two `RANDOM` numbers resulting in each output number greater than 1, and *two* combinations resulting in 1 (one random number equal 0 and the other 1, or both numbers equal 2^15-1), making a result of 1 twice as likely as any other number.

Comment: @l0b0 good call, thanks. I think I corrected it, with the "minor" caveat that the program might never terminate if you have really bad luck =)

Comment: RANDOM is  a bash extension, it is not a general solution to getting a random number in a shell script.

Answer (score 2):

`shuf` is probably what you want:

```
$ shuf -i 50000-150000 -n 1
148495
```

Comment: Nice and easy and as uniform as it gets, no sweat ;-)

Comment: Thank you but one more question. How can I use shuf command inside the bash script with cat command?